$\Bbb Q(\alpha)=\Bbb Q(\alpha^4)$ if $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial of degree $n\ge3$
Let $f$ be a irreducibe polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ and $n=\deg f\ge3$. Let $K$ be its splitting field with $[K:\Bbb Q]=n!$ and $f(\alpha)=0$. Prove that $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=\Bbb Q(\alpha^4)$.
I think $[K:\Bbb Q]=n!\iff Gal(K/\Bbb Q)\cong S_n$ since $f$ is irreducible and hence separable. Now I read this. But I don't know how this will help.
I also know a related result: $\alpha$ separable iff $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^{p^n}),\forall n$. but this will not do in characteristic 0.
What should I do? is the number $4$ necessary or can be an arbitrary number $m\ge 4$? Thanks in advance.

For $m=4$, the question has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922474/field-extension-splitting-field-and-galois-theory?noredirect=1

A great find @Tri !

Andreas Caranti's argument settles the case of $m>4$ as well when $n>3$. The other option to $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^m)=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha^m)=\Bbb{Q}$, when $\alpha$ is a root of a binomial $x^m-a\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$. So the conjugates of $\alpha$ have the form $\alpha\zeta^{2\pi i k/m}$ for some selected exponents $k$. It follows that the stabilizer of $\alpha$ is an abelian group. But that stabilizer is also $\simeq S_{n-1}$. The case $n=3$ needs a different argument. Shouldn't be difficult.

Silly of me. In the case $n=3$ the product of three of those conjugates is equal to $-f(0)$ so a rational number et cetera.
